# Allow all mimetype in GET request

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking, nsxmlparser

I am using `AFNetworking` 2.0 (v2.4.1) and I would like to do GET request with any `mimetype`.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = <ALL_MIME_TYPE>;
```

How can I set `acceptableContentTypes` to get all mime types for `XML` and for `JSON`?

Answer (score 0):

set it to nil ,it will not check [github source code for AFURLResponseSerialization.m](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/72be6947595211431b66c305422fdbfd88b3b37a/AFNetworking/AFURLResponseSerialization.m)